# CakePHP bake stacked by database Config:

Tags: cakephp

It's the first time I made a bake through the CakePHP console.
I run the cmd as admin and there is a strange thing that after setting 
the database config: (default/test) it is stucked there and I don't know 
why.

The environment path is setting up correctly.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "stacked"? The screen you're showing is normal behavior. If you just press Entere, you'll be using the default connection($default in database.php).

Comment: i mean it stopped there and nothing happened

Comment: Well, yes, you need to follow the steps. Press Enter to continue there. Or you can use the command "cake bake all" if you want it to handle everything for you.

Comment: yes i already done that i when i enter by [default] it is stopped and nothing happened since 30minutes